# Javascript hide fields on select

Tags: javascript, html

I have three text fields, I want to show the first and hide the second and third when option 1 is selected, and the opposite when option two is selected.

I did the following:

```
<script language="javascript">

        function hola(x) {

            if(x == 1) {
                document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility="visible";
                document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility="hidden"; 
            }

            if(x == 2)  {
                document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility="hidden";
                document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility="visible"; 
            }
        }
    </script>

<body onload='hola(1)'>

<label  class="field6" for="shower_times">how many showers each takes per day: </label>
<SELECT name="shower_times" onChange="hola(this.value)">
<OPTION value="1">1</OPTION>
<OPTION value="2">2</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<div id="div1">
<BR>
<label  class="field6" for="hour"> hour of the shower: </label><input type="text"   name="hour" class="input"> 
</div>

<div id="div2">
<label  class="field6" for="hour1">hour of first shower: </label><input type="text" name="hour1" class="input"> 
<BR>
<label  class="field6" for="hour2">hour of second shower: </label><input type="text" name="hour2" class="input"> 
</div>
```

It's working find when I change the option, but the problem is that at the beginning I want it to show only the first field, that's why I used

```
<body onload='hola(1)'>
```

but it's not working, it's showing all three at the beginning.

the code seems to work alone, 
but all when I add it to other codes as this one http://jsfiddle.net/3YZBm/1/ , this part is not working the way I mentioned

Comment: Why don't you just set the second and third to default not display on load? I.E. set their visibility to hidden with a css class or in line.

Comment: Your code works fine. Whatever the issue is, it doesn't seem to be in the code you provided.

Comment: Seems to run fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TaeCp/

Comment: @CrazyTrain You were right I just tested the code alone, and it worked fine. but with other codes on the same page, this problem occures

Comment: Then we need to see the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @CrazyTrain this is my whole code http://jsfiddle.net/3YZBm/

Comment: @j08691 it's not working here: http://jsfiddle.net/3YZBm/

Comment: @maggie: Please read this: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @maggie - the HTML in your fiddle is 100% invalid.

Comment: @j08691 take this as a short code: http://jsfiddle.net/3YZBm/1/
it still has the same problem

Comment: Wait... you have a `<body>` in the middle of your page?

Comment: @j08691 why is it invalid? 
btw I'm not working on fiddle I just copied it there to show you the code

Comment: @maggie Why is it invalid? Your tags are in the wrong place. If you want to use jsFiddle you need to create valid HTML, otherwise there's not much point.

Comment: just use this: http://jsfiddle.net/3YZBm/1/ , I deleted unnecessary lines

Comment: @j08691 but it showing me the same problem

Comment: @CrazyTrain I needed it to use onload

Comment: @CrazyTrain did you check the output of http://jsfiddle.net/3YZBm/1/

Comment: Yes, I looked at that. You've already been told your markup is invalid. It seems that you need to start with some basic tutorials before trying to develop your application. And `jsFiddle` puts your HTML automatically inside `<body>` tags, so even if you have it correctly positioned at the top, it may not work.

Comment: @CrazyTrain who said my Markup is invalid ?! it's working! just with this problem

Comment: Why are you asking me "who said my Markup is invalid"? You already know that @j08691 told you that. You even responded to his comment.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I already said I'm not using jsfiddle, I just copied the code to show you.

Comment: I don't care what you're using. Even if you're not using jsFiddle, the code in the jsFiddle you provided is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to go with pure JS, you could do something like this...

The HTML (slightly modified)...

```
<label  class="field6" for="shower_times">how many showers each takes per day: </label>
<SELECT name="shower_times"  id="mselect" onChange="hola();">
<OPTION value="1">1</OPTION>
<OPTION value="2">2</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<div id="div1">
<BR>
<label  class="field6" for="hour"> hour of the shower: </label><input type="text"   name="hour" class="input"> 
</div>

<div id="div2">
<label  class="field6" for="hour1">hour of first shower: </label><input type="text" name="hour1" class="input"> 
<BR>
<label  class="field6" for="hour2">hour of second shower: </label><input type="text" name="hour2" class="input"> 
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS (optional to hide the 2 fields by default since 1 is selected by default)...

```
#div2 {
 display:none;
}
```

And the JS modified by Maggie...

```
  function hola() {
    var mselect  =  document.getElementById("mselect");
    var mselectvalue = mselect.options[mselect.selectedIndex].value;
    var mdivone =  document.getElementById("div1");
    var mdivtwo =  document.getElementById("div2");

      if (mselectvalue == 2) {
       mdivtwo.style.display = "block";
       mdivone.style.display = "none";

      }
      else {
      mdivtwo.style.display = "none";
      mdivone.style.display = "block";
      }  
}
```

and Maggie's modified solution [to back](http://jsfiddle.net/nv7ED/14) it up!

Comment: -1 No one needs jQuery for simple JavaScript. OP has a specific issue that needs to be solved. This doesn't help OP discover what the issue is.

Comment: @blachawk I checked the demo, that's not what I want

Comment: @blachawk: Even with jQuery, your code didn't do anything similar to what OP described in the question. Your demos do nothing to address the issue described in the question.

Comment: @maggie - check out my updated fiddle here and let me know if this addresses your issue - http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/nv7ED/13/

Comment: @blachawk I updated it a little that's how I want it: http://jsfiddle.net/nv7ED/14/

Comment: @maggie awesome!  nice job in expanding on the code I provided and making your own solution! I'll go ahead and update my code to reflect on your solution.

Comment: the problem is when I add it to my initial code like i did here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3YZBm/4/ I still encounter the same problem (JUST AT THE BEGINNENG, it's showing all 3 fields)

Comment: @maggie easy fix, just remember to add that css{} code to that fiddle as well, just like we did in the other fiddle examples.

Comment: @blachawk Ohh ok perfect !