# On load, how to check against multiple values in condition, in the form of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing a page title into a JavaScript variable every time a page is loaded. This is what I have so far

```
var msubpagetitle = $('#content-titlebanner h1').text().trim();
console.log(msubpagetitle);
```

For example, this will produce a result of...

```
Support
```

How can I say...

If this variable is "**not**" `About` or `Contact` or `Bio`, then perform the following condition(...)

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to include jquery in the question title, trust the tagging system

Comment: So, what you're asking is... How do i test of variable x is equal to "About" or "Contact", and if it isn't, do y? Why are you asking this? ... Unless i'm missing something, you're asking how to write an if statement.

Comment: Understood.  I wouldn't mind learning how to perform this action with or without it.

Comment: @Kevin, Yes that is what I am asking for.  I'm asking this because by default, my content management system is loading something onto a page I don't need on every page.  I just need it displayed in the DOM on "some" pages.  For the pages that don't need it (a hand few), then don't show it.

Comment: Like the if statement **you wrote** in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597550/javascript-hide-fields-on-select/17597791#17597791

Comment: Sorry, i'm having trouble understanding why you brought this question to stackoveflow... it seems like something i would have expected you to already know, seeing your question/answer history. `if (x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3) doThis();`

Comment: If/else or switch, or you can store About/Contact/Bio into an array and then check if title is in array ( http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)

Comment: @blackhawk I don't think you mentioned the other variable exist part in the question

Comment: @keypaul, that is exactly why I posted this question - thank you for bringing me up to speed on conditionally measuring against an Array of values! I apologize to everyone on here that I didn't say it that way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whithout Jquery, one way is to make use of `.indexOf()`, that returns `-1` if argument was not found in the array...

```
if(['About', 'Contact', 'Bio'].indexOf(msubpagetitle) == -1) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something like this...that you can keep adding, without writing variables over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

```
var msubpagetitle = $('#content-titlebanner h1').text().trim();
if( $.inArray( msubpagetitle, ['About','Contact','Bio'] ) == -1 )
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, because my list of variables values may grow or shrink depending on how many pages I am dealing with. I will try this out in my code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery for that

```
if(document.title != 'About' && document.title != 'Contact' && document.title != 'Bio')
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the OP's code on what is considered page title in this case

Comment: @Huangism well, I understand title as title. I see that he is using jquery selector for another tag, but it can be equal to title just by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need figure out if the title doesn't equal any of those strings. In this case it would have be `true`, `true`, `true`, for title != your strings

```
var title = $('#content-titlebanner h1').text().trim();

if(title != "About" && title != "Contact" && title != "Bio") {
  // do something here
}
```